# Measuring freedom in republican theories?

Tags: reference-request, political-philosophy

The liberal, or pure negative, approach to freedom, which identifies freedom with non-interference, often allows for freedom to be measured, e.g. in the works of Ian Carter and Matthew Kramer.

Are there republican theories, those identifying freedom as non-domination, that offer a way to measure the freedom of a person or society as well?

Comment: Those aren't any liberals I know. Non-interference? You're joking, right?

Comment: Relevance to my question? None. And a quick google search would have prevented your comment. http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/liberalism/#NegLib

Comment: How do you define "republican" here?

Comment: It is a label which the participants of the debate about the nature of freedom use. You can take a look here: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/republicanism/